# Bootstrap-sass gem fails to load js for dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I am beginner of ruby on rails programming lately I have been doing demo project with twitter bootstrap as CSS framework. I have included bootstrap-sass in gem file and bundled, all the part of bootstrap works fine except drop-down menu and java script function. Please suggest me where I have made mistake.This is my gem file:

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
group :production do
gem 'pg'
end
gem 'devise'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1.1'
```

Here is my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

My application.html.erb file looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Mirror</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true   %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
</body>
```

Lastly my application.css.scss looks this way

```
/*
@import "bootstrap";
* This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include   all the files
* listed below.
*
* Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets,    vendor/assets/stylesheets,
* or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
*
* You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
* compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
* defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
* file per style scope.
*
*= require_tree
*= require_self
```

I would appreciate any suggestion or hint provided. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this to the end of your application.js file :

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
```

The dropdown should work now.

Comment: Yes, this works for me! But I wonder why it needs to be like this. I've found someone else there has the same problem https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/issues/319

Comment: Sorry but this question was not brought by me so I cannot mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

A less hacky fix would be to add the `jquery-turbolinks` gem.

The reason the dropdowns aren't working is because they are bound to `$(document).ready` instead of `$(document).on('page:change')`, which is what turbolinks uses.

The jquery-turbolinks gem will make it so that ready calls will also respond to turbolink's page:change calls.

***Step 1:*** Add gem `jquery-turbolinks` to your Gemfile.

***Step 2:*** Add it to your JavaScript manifest file, in this order:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//
// ... your other scripts here ...
//
//= require turbolinks
```

*Badabing!*

Comment: Didn't work for me, had to resort to `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();`

Comment: Sorry to hear that, Ben. If you had to do that, then it's definitely a turbolinks issue of some kind. Ah well, you gotta do what you gotta do!

Comment: jquery-turbolinks is now deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Try putting

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

into your application.js file. Bootstrap-sprockets gives you all the bootstrap js files. More info about requiring bootstrap components (individually) can be found from [bootstrap-sass documentation](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#javascript-with-sprockets-or-mincer).